# Flutter Tabs is throwing a null pointer exception -> Material.of(context).color evaluates to null

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I am following the example expansiona_panels_demo.dart provided in the flutter gallery found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart). My objective is to introduce a TabBar and TabBarView within the expansion panel body. As of now this is breaking because a null pointer exception being thrown within tabs.dart. This is within _TabBarState and it's doing a comparison against the `widget.indicatorColor` If you were to look at the demo I am trying to call new BookTabs() at line 251.

```
if (color.value == Material.of(context).color.value)
```

Here Material.of(context).color is null

To consolidate the code I have put my tabs in a stateful widget. When I place the widget within a CollapsibleBody widget as defined in the gallery example then the *getter 'value' called on null * is thrown. Currently I am at a loss as to how to resolve this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class BookTabs extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _BookTabs createState() => new _BookTabs();
}

class _BookTabs extends State<BookTabs> with 
SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

TabController _tabController;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Column(
   children: <Widget>[
    new TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        labelColor: Colors.blue,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.indigo,             
        tabs: [
          new Tab(text: 'Books'),
          new Tab(text: 'Authors')
        ]
    ),
    new Expanded(
        child: new TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,

            children: [
              new SafeArea(
                  top: false,
                  bottom: false,
                  child:
                  new Text("Books", style: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .subhead)),

              new SafeArea(
                  top: false,
                  bottom: false,
                  child: new Text("Authors", style: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .subhead))
            ])
    )
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

From Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.2.6, on Mac OS X 10.13.3 17D102, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 0.2.6 at /Users/minime/flutter
• Framework revision 1d067220da (4 days ago), 2018-03-29 22:14:04 -0700
• Engine revision 9af82c5a1a
• Dart version 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-e305117519
```

Comment: Do you have a `MaterialApp` as parent of `BookTabs`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't use [`MaterialApp`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) as parent of `BookTabs`.

If you don't want a `MaterialApp`, you at least need to wrap it in [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html)

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping the element in Material fixed the problem!

Comment: Thanks again that was a tough one for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem using `Scaffold.of(context)` and managed to solve it by wrapping all my widgets under a `Builder` wrapper.

Check the [`BuildContext`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) docs on how to do it, when you need a valid context it's the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! The code was in a builder I just needed to wrap in a Material  const.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the widget in a Material class fixed the issue.

```
new Material(color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .dialogBackgroundColor, child: new BookTabs()
                    )
```